# Java code ported to Objective-C is very slow

Tags: cocoa

I want to illustrate a concrete example to understand if there are best (and worst) practices when java code is rewritten in Objective-C.

I've ported the Java implementation of [org.apache.wicket.util.diff.myers](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/J2EE/wicket-1.4/org/apache/wicket/util/diff/myers/MyersDiff.java.htm) to Objective-C on OSX Snow Leopard (Xcode 4) but the result runs very slowly compared to the Java version.

The method with worst performances is buildPath, it mainly does

- sparse array access (diagonal variable, this array is allocated inside method and isn't returned)
- random array access (orig and rev variables)
- allocation of PathNode and its subclasses (an object with three properties, only property is an element using internally by array)
- strings comparison

Cocoa hasn't any collection class to work easily with sparse arrays so I've allocated an array with malloc, this dramatically improved the first version based on NSDictionary and zillion of NSNumber's object allocated to be used as key.

The PathNode(s) allocation is done using the normal syntax `[[MyClass alloc] init]`, they aren't autoreleased because are added to an NSMutableArray (but are released immediately after adding it to array)

Random access to array is done using [NSArray objectAtIndex:index] I think (but I can be wrong) that moving it to an C-like doesn't speedup so much.

Do you have any idea to improve performance, where bottlenecks can be found?
Using instruments 74% of time is spent on allocation, how can I improve allocation?

**EDIT** I've submitted my actual implementation to [github](https://github.com/visualdiffer/DiffUtils), obviously is an alpha version not ready for production and doesn't use any efficient objective-c construct

Comment: Try to use "stack objects" as explained in this article: http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-15-stack-and-heap-objects-in-objective-c.html
They're quite limited but if you need the data inside the buildPath routine only this can help in reducing allocation time.

Comment: Thanks "stack objects" help me to remove a malloc/free but the main code depends (and returns) an object containing array them is allocated inside the loop. I've refined my question

Answer (score 2):

You're off to an excellent start. You've profiled the code, isolated the actual bottleneck, and are now focused on how to address it.

The first question is which allocation is costly? Obviously you should focus on that one first.

There are several efficient ways to deal with sparse arrays. First, look at [NSPointerArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPointerArray_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html), which is designed to hold NULL values. It does not promise to be efficient for sparse arrays, but @bbum (who knows such things) [suggests it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354955/how-to-do-sparse-array-in-cocoa).

Next, look at [NSHashMap](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSHashTable_class/Introduction/Introduction.html), which is certainly efficient for sparse collections (it's a dictionary), and supports non-object keys (i.e. you don't need to create an `NSNumber`).

Finally, if allocation really is your problem, there are various tricks to work around it. The most common is to reuse objects rather than destroying one and creating another. This is how `UITableViewCell` works (and `NSCell` in a different way).

Finally, if you switch to Core Foundation objects, you can create your own specialized memory allocator, but that really is a last resort.

Note that 10.6 supports ARC (without zeroing weak references). ARC dramatically improves performance around a lot of common memory management patterns. For example, the very common pattern of "retain+autorelease+return" is highly optimized under ARC. ("retain" doesn't exist in the language in ARC, but it does still exist in the compiler, and ARC is much faster than doing by hand.) I highly recommend switching to ARC in any code you can.

Comment: I'm working on Snow Leopard but XCode 4 for SL doesn't support ARC

Comment: @dafi Yes; Snow Leopard can run programs that use ARC that were built on Lion, but Xcode on Snow Leopard cannot build programs that use ARC. It's missing a library it would need for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`NSPointerArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPointerArray_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html) class as a replacement for your sparse array. `NSPointerArray` allows `null` elements.

If you post the code thats generating the bulk of your allocations, we might be able to help you more.

Comment: I've commit on github https://github.com/visualdiffer/DiffUtils and updated my question the class with performance bottleneck is https://github.com/visualdiffer/DiffUtils/blob/master/src/DiffUtils/myers/MyersDiff.m