# How do I add data into NSMutableArray by manually assigning index?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

Is there any way to manually control which index we want to add our data to with an `NSMutableArray`? In PHP, for example, we can do:

```
$foo[2] = "fafa";
$foo[8] = "haha";
```

Can the manual assigning of indexing be done on `NSMutableArray`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because it's not *entirely* clear to me that TeamStar wants a sparse array, I'll just mention that you can assign objects to specific indexes within an `NSMutableArray` – so long as the array is already long enough – using `-replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` and the other `-replace…` methods.

Comment: Well the reason is because the radio button i use is supposed to update the array row[] not add more data into the array in case the users decides to change the option...

Answer (score 4):

`NSMutableArray`s are not sparse -- they cannot have gaps where no objects are stored. It is possible to insert an object at any index from 0 to length - 1, using `insertObject:atIndex:` (as Edu mentioned), but other than that you can only append objects (using `addObject:`).

If you need to associate objects with arbitrary integers, you can use an [`NSMapTable`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMapTable_class/Reference/NSMapTable.html) -- the [functional interface](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIHBGID) allows integer keys, or simply use an `NSMutableDictionary`, with `NSNumber` keys (as drewag suggested).

See also: [How to do sparse array in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354955/how-to-do-sparse-array-in-cocoa)

Answer (score 2):

No that is not possible. I would suggest using an NSMutableDictionary instead. You can use NSNumbers as indexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)insertObject:(id)anObject atIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

**Important** Raises an NSRangeException if index is greater than the number of elements in the array.

Comment: Raises an `NSRangeException` if `index` is greater than the number of elements in the array.

Comment: You can use a for loop and fill the array with zeros. But I don't think i'ts a good idea so, have you tried NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: but isn't that making it into a function?
can i use e.g.;
`@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *rangenans;`
followed by:
`[rangenans insertObject:label1.text atIndex:0];`